# When should I use a comma before the word "who"?

Tags: commas, clauses

Should I use a comma before the word *who*?  This sentence is confusing me:

> I made this blog because I want to help all of the other people 
>   who have problems that are similar to mine.

If I did use a comma in that sentence, then what would be the benefits & disadvantages?

In what cases should a comma be put before the word who?

Comment: Commas, or their absence, can change the meaning of a sentence in profound ways. This is the main reason why commas must be correct. The ability of commas to change the meaning of sentences is most apparent with the word who. But to understand how this occurs, you must first understand the difference between restrictive and non-restrictive clauses, in absence of which you cannot understand anything.

Comment: YACQ - yet another comma question. Are there algorithms in place that could auto-close YACQs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reworking the sentence so it flows more smoothly, and doesn't feel like it needs a comma:

> I made this blog because I want to help all the people who have similar problems.

Comment: Good advice. You could even remove the "all the", too, and use a preposition instead of "who have": ***I made this blog because I want to help people with similar problems.*** (It's funny how pruning often leads to more pruning. One time, when revising a term paper, I managed to trim a 7-sentence paragraph into a single, 13-word sentence. Huge improvement.)